# Icon of my software don't appear

Tags: 12.04

As it is said in the title I have a problem on the appearance on my icon's software. Just see below :

[image]

Comment: Have you installed a new icon-set ? A theme if you prefer.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Nothing, I have just installed dconf-editor and gconf-editor

Comment: Unfortunatly it does nothing :/

Comment: yep, my bad. It's desktop, not dektop. So try the command : `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface icon-theme "default" && gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface icon-theme "ubuntu-mono-dark"`

Comment: No problem I saw the error, and edit my comment. Unfortunatly that doesn't work.
It is only in Applications menu that I have the problem

Comment: If you open `nautilus /usr/share/applications/`, do you see every icons ? If yes, you have to get rid of your application-menu, or reinstall it.

Comment: Thank you for your help. When I go to /usr/share/applications/ i don't see all the icon's. Lot of icons are just grey

Comment: can you post the return of the command `ls /usr/share/icons` please ?

Answer (score 1):

You have in some way broken your icon-theme. You'll need to reinstall the icons.

Type in a terminal :

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge ubuntu-mono gnome-icon-theme hicolor-icon-theme humanity-icon-theme
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-mono gnome-icon-theme hicolor-icon-theme humanity-icon-theme
sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Then apply another theme and restore the theme by default :

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface icon-theme "default" && gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface icon-theme "ubuntu-mono-dark"
```

Comment: I do what you said, but nothing changes... Same problem :/
Incredible problem ^^

Comment: I edited my answer with a more brutal way to do this. Try it please.

Comment: I try it, it turns my Applications menu in english, and all icons are now the same (basic file orange). But like in my screenshot, the icon stay dark with the red point

Comment: You will be able to translate your menu in your language with the tool provided in the System Configuration. In the mean time, you can also do `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tiheum/equinox && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install faenza-icon-theme myunity && myunity`. In that program, change the icon theme to Faenza.